# How do I kick off a simple crontab job?

Tags: unix, cron

After editing using crontab -e, my crontab schedule started.  I killed the process but then I don't know how to start it again?

Did some googling already.  Tried sudo service cron start, nothing seems to be happening...

Comment: What is the reason to kill cron daemon? What is your operating system?

Comment: Which process did you kill? The process started by `cron`? Please show at least the relevant `crontab` line[s].

Comment: I am using Raspbian.  Yes, I killed the process started by cron

`#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
raspistill -o /home/pi/timelapse/$DATE.jpg`